# Conway Complex Analysis problem 1.3.3

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c>0$ be fixed. Describe the set of points $z$ satisfying $$|z-a| - |z+a| = 2c$$

for every possible choice of $a,c$. If $a$ is any complex number, using a rotation of the plane, describe the locus of points satisfying the above equation.

I was able to describe the set when $a \in \mathbb{R}$ but when $a \in \mathbb{C}$ I'm a bit stuck. I wanted to repeat my procedure as I did for the first part, but I don't think I see what is meant by using a rotation to solve this. I know what rotations are but I guess I don't see how to actually apply this hint.

What I tried was assuming $z=x+iy$ and $a=r+it$ and trying to evaluate the moduli and square twice as I did in the first part, but this didn't do anything that felt right. The algebra was fine but the answer doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=re^{i\theta}$. We may transform the given equation as follows:
$$|e^{-i\theta}|\left(|z-re^{i\theta}| -|z+re^{i\theta})|\right) = 2c. $$
Implying,
$$|w-r| -|w+r| =2c, \tag{1}$$ where $w=e^{-i\theta} z$.

You know the complete set of solutions to (1). Now, $w$ is a solution of (1) if and only if $z=we^{i\theta}$ is a solution of
$$|z-a| -|z+a| =2c.\tag{2}$$

In this way you can determine the set of solutions to (2). Now, what we did here is, we multiplied $z$ by $e^{-i\theta}$ to get $w$. Multiplying by $e^{-i\theta}$ simply means rotation of plane through an angle $-\theta$. Thus to solve given equality (equation (2)), we need to rotate plane through an angle $-\theta$ and then solve another equation (equation (1)).

Comment: I think you changed the sign at one point

Comment: Yes. Thanks for identifying.